# Правильно ли реализована инкапсуляция?

Tags: java, ооп

Правильно ли я реализовал инкапсуляцию в этом примере:

```
class Students {

    static class Characteristics {

        public String[] getStudents() {
            return new String[]{"Ануфриев Владимир" + getF(),
                    "Бевский Максим" + getF(),
                    "Войтович Степан" + getF(),
                    "Годун Олександр" + getF(),
                    "Дмитренко Степан" + getV(),
                    "Ермолаев Иван" + getF(),
                    "Евсиков Игорь" + getF(),
                    "Жебрак Алексей" + getF(),
                    "Забой Максим" + getF(),
                    "Записоцкий Дмитрий" + getF()};
        }

        public String getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public void setV(String v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public String getF() {
            return f;
        }

        public void setF(String f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        private String v;
        private String f;
    }

    public static void voting(String studentsList[], String property) {
        for (String st : studentsList) {
            if (st.contains(property)) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(st + ", поэтому и выбран старостой");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Characteristics characteristics = new Characteristics();
        characteristics.setV(" ответственный, умный и активный");
        characteristics.setF(" хороший, но посредственный");
        for (String students : characteristics.getStudents()) {
            System.out.println(students);
        }
        voting(characteristics.getStudents(), characteristics.getV());
    }
}
```

Comment: данные сокриты - инкапсуляция реализована.

Comment: А к объектам можно придраться? Есть вероятность, что на ООП это не похоже?

Comment: Нет, ни фига, двойка за дизайн

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, следует выделить отдельный класс для студентов, в котором будут приватные поля(Имя, Фамилия, Характеристика). И уже оперировать обьектом класса Student.

Comment: т.е., внутренний класс Charasteristics сделать внешним?

Comment: Сделать класс, который будет содержать информацию про одного студента. Назову этот класс Student. Каждый "студент" будет содержать Имя, Фамилию, Характеристика - приватные переменные строки. Возможно, следует создать массив таких студентов, и при создании обьекта Student, задавать им характеристику. И если хотите , пусть тогда будет 2 класс StudentsVoting, который будет определять старосту, по определенным характеритикам. И в main. Вам останется создать обьект класса StudentsVoting, и допустим вызвать его метод choose();. Мне кажется, можно сделать так

Comment: А можно продемонстрировать это приблизительно хотя бы? Потому что я пока понимаю, что нужно внутренний класс Charasteristics вынести из класса Students.

Comment: @Никита У вас есть метод `main` можно создать класс `Main`, обычный стартовый класс. Создать класс `Student` он будет хранить информацию о студенте, также в нем будут Getter-ы и Setter-ы. Я бы сделал, еще одно поле под характеристику Студента. Можно создать класс `Monitor`( вместо вашего внутреннего класса), который будет содержать метод `voting`. В классе `Main` создать ArrayList студентов: дать имена, характеристики, фамилии. Потом вызвать метод `voting` класса `Monitor`. Радоваться жизни

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, да, но выглядит очень странно архитектура.
Сама концепция инкапсуляции говорит о том, что к объекту не должно быть доступа извне. Для этого, есть методы `get` и `set`.
А так, лучше для каждого объекта создавать свой класс со своими методами.

Comment: А что конкретно выглядит странно? Может, что девушек в группе нету?

Comment: Т.е., нужно создать массив объектов? Был бы признателен, если бы Вы выложили пример кода.